# Ivr mask input digits - Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I have an IVR and I store the digits in a database.
But I don't want to show the digits in Asterisk console.
I already remove the option 'dtmf' from file logger.conf, but still appears in console.
I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only way really not show dtmf input on console ->rewrite asterisk core and create your own c++ application for asterisk. That require very special knowledge(not think more then 500 people over word ever did that) or high level of c/c++ experience.

If you just want remove verbose messages like "user entered XXX" - you can change in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf verbose level to 0 and turn it off on console by "core set verbose"

Note, anyway anyone with minimal asterisk knowledge and access to console can change it back to see that.

Comment: With the changes in logger.conf messages like "[Feb 28 10:07:53] DTMF[17207]: channel.c:4151 __ast_read: DTMF begin '1' received on SIP/40018-000017fb" are not displayed.

But still appears 'User Entered XXXX'. Can I remove this message in a safe way? Now I am thinking how companies store dtmf safely?

Comment: I already answered above. Please read it carefully. You have grant security of such system, not allow anyone access box with asterisk.